# How do I use page name as textbox value

Tags: javascript, variables, textbox, popup

There's a couple of things I'm trying to achieve with Javascript. I'm a bit of a noob, so bear with me.

Firstly I'm using this code to create a popup window:

HTML:

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('contact.html');"><img src="request.jpg"/></a>
```

JS:

```
var sPage;

    function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
        var sPath=window.location.pathname;
        var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        window.name = sPage;
}
```

This part works fine, but what I'm then trying to do is take the current page name and put it into the value of a textbox in 'contact.html'.

This is the code I'm using on the popup page to try and do that:

```
function add(text){
    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("prodcode");
    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + window.name;
}
```

This seems to work when it's a normal page I'm linking to, but it wont work if it's a popup. I also can't figure out how to get rid of the extension from the page name.

I realise there are probably a million better ways to do this, but this is the one that seems to make most sense to me. I've looked at cookies, but I can't seem to figure them out.

I know I'm asking a lot, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question right, you could pass the window name as a query param in the URL you're passing to your `newPopup` function, then grab it in the contact.html page to put it into the box.

For example, your `newPopup` function could add the query parameter to the url like so:

```
function newPopup(url) {
    var sPath=window.location.pathname;
    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var windowName = sPage.split(".")[0];    
    popupWindow = window.open(url + '?window_name=' + windowName,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
    window.name = windowName;
}
```

Then, in your contact.html file, grab the query param when setting the value of your text box, using this sort of logic:

```
function parseURLParams(name, locat) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(locat);
    if (results) {
        return results[1] || "";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
function add(text) {
    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("prodcode");
    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + parseURLParams("window_name", window.location.href);
}
```

Hope it helps!